# congruency of triangles in hyperbolic and spherical geometry

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

In Euclidean geometry, we have the following congruencies of triangles: side-side-side, side-angle-side, angle-angle-side = angle-side-angle (because of the angle sum) and side-side-angle (only if the side opposite to the angle is larger than the other given side). Angle-angle-angle does never hold.

My question is this: when are triangles congruent in the hyperbolic and the spherical case and what are the conditions under which the congruencies hold?

Does anybody know a reference where all these congruencies are derived from the respective laws of sines and cosines?

Comment: in hyperbolic and spherical, angle-angle-angle always holds.

Comment: Thanks Will, I already suspected this. Do you know something about the others? Do they need to be modified?